# html and CSS style how to fixed the form after click event button

Tags: html, css, forms

i have a webpage that includes Google Map , form  and table that shows the results based on the user input from the form.

the problem is that after the user click the search button the form move down and the user becomes unable to use it again.
[image]

after the user click search button the button  the form move down 
[image]
based on the answer 
[image]

## code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Custom Markers</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap">
        </script>

         <style>
          /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */
          #map {
            height: 400px;
            width:1045px;
            float: right;


          }
          /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

          }
           #form {
                  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
                  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
                  background: linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
                  margin: auto;
                  width: 550px;
                  height: 450px;
               position: absolute;

                  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
                  font-size: 14px;
                  font-style: italic;
                  line-height: 24px;
                  font-weight: bold;
                  color: #09C;
                  text-decoration: none;
                  border-radius: 10px;
                  padding: 10px;
                  border: 1px solid #999;
                  border: inset 1px solid #333;
                 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                 box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
               }



        </style>

 </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
<!-- create form for dropdown list-->

  <!--create  dropdown list site names-->

  <div id="form">
    <form method ="post" action ="" name="submit_form">
        <table border="0" width="30%">
            <tr>
               <td>Site Location</td>
               <td>employee Name</td>
               <td>Inspection Date</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td><select id="site_locationID"  name = "site_locationName">
                      <option value="">Select Site</option>
</tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type ="submit" name="query_submit" value ="Search" /></td>
      </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
  </div><!-- div of the  form-->
```

i know that the error is in the style but do not know how to fix it.

Comment: why dont you give #form button an absolute position, and everything would be 7elo

Comment: because i needed to be relative to the map

Comment: show  your HTML Code

Comment: i edit my question and add HTML code

Answer (score 1):

add `top` & `left` property

```
#form {top:0; left:0;}
```

Comment: i added your answer but it did not work it moves the form to the top left  i will add  the picture to the question

Comment: try this css -  tr td{vertical-align:top;}

Comment: its little long  HTML with PHP  isn't the problem in the css ?